# Get VERSION from main file

Tags: ruby

I have a lib/xyz.rb which contains:

```
VERSION=1.2.3
```

Now i would like to access that number by another program. This program should work not only for the defined file xyz.rb but to all files directly under lib/ but not under lib/projectname/*.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might need to create a module `XYZ` like

```
 #lib/xyz.rb
    module XYZ
     VERSION = "1.2.3"
    end
```

and then any file directly under `lib` suppose `abc.rb`

```
#lib/abc.rb
require_relative 'xyz'
module XYZ
  p VERSION
end
```